# Is there a literary technique for when someone knows what will happen even though he has never experienced it?

Tags: literary-techniques

For example, I have never experienced this myself but I thought if a potato chip was squished/pressed under a metal surface and a plastic surface, it is more likely to stick to the metal rather than plastic.

My instinct tells me that even though it has never happened to me.

Like foreshadowing, being a literary technique, means when the audience can guess what will happen in the upcoming events due to the current situation, I was wondering if there was a technique for this too.

Comment: Prediction, precognition, foreknowledge, premonition, prophecy. For literary techniques in general, try asking here https://writing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [thought experiment?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_experiment)